# Javascript to hide selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to hide selected options:

```
function connect()
{
    $(".selectbox option").show();
    $(".selectbox").each(function(i) { 
        var obj = $(".selectbox option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']");
        if($(this).val() != "") obj.hide();     
    }); 
}

function to()
{
    $(".selectboxes option").show();
    $(".selectboxes").each(function(i) { 
        var obj = $(".selectboxes option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']");
        if($(this).val() != "") obj.hide();     
    }); 
}
```

but my problem now is that, I use PHP to generate the select tag, and in that php code i have a condition that once it sees this value it will automatically add selected=selected. but my JS would still display that variable in the drop down even though it is already selected. i tried adding:

```
$('.selectboxes option:selected').find("option").hide();
```

but it did not work. any idea on how should i solve this problem?

BTW: i forgot to mention that, the php code will generate multiple select tags with the same values that will use that function, thus when i have 3 select tags 1 will have the pre selected value and the other 2 will be null, now when i click on either 2 of those that have no values selected yet i can still see in the drop down the choice that was already pre selected in select 1, what i wanted to do is that it should be automatically hidden, with that function it will not hide it until i select other choices from the drop down. since this line:

```
$(".selectbox option").show();
```

would display all choices in the drop down, is there a condition for it to exempt "this" value?

SELECT PART:

```
for($z=0;$z<$rows_updatedrow;$z++)
{
?>
<select id = "sc" name = "connect_array[]" class="input-select selectbox" onchange = "connect()">
<option value = "">--Select--</option>
<?php
for($zz=0;$zz<$rows_getconnect;$zz++)
{
    $data_getconnect = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_getconnect);
    $field_name_getconnect[] = $data_getconnect['field_name'];
    $field_display_getconnect[] = $data_getconnect['field_display'];
    $field_type_getconnect[] = $data_getconnect['field_type'];
    if((($field_name_getconnect[$zz] == "friends_name" && $connect == 2) || $field_type_getconnect[$zz] == "email") && $z == 0){
    $selected = "selected=selected";
    }else{
    $selected = "";
    }
?>
<option value = "<?php echo $field_name_getconnect[$zz]; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $field_display_getconnect[$zz]; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
 connect to 
<br/>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
<div class = "right">
<?php
for($a=0;$a<$rows_updatedrow;$a++)
{
?> 
<select name = "to_array[]" class="input-select selectboxes" onchange = "to()">
<option class = "option" value = "">--Select--</option>
<?php
for($aa=0;$aa<$rows_getto;$aa++)
{
    $data_getto = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_getto);
    $field_name_getto[] = $data_getto['field_name'];
    $field_display_getto[] = $data_getto['field_display'];
    $field_type_getto[] = $data_getto['field_type'];
    if((($field_name_getto[$aa] == "friends_name" && $to == 2) || $field_type_getto[$aa] == "email") && $a == 0){
    $selected = "selected=selected";
    }else{
    $selected = "";
    }
?>
<option class = "option" value = "<?php echo $field_name_getto[$aa]; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $field_display_getto[$aa]; ?></option>
<?php
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the selected option in your selector - no need to find option - as that will return you an empty array

```
$('.selectboxes option:selected').hide();
// get rid of .find('option')
```

To exempt `this` value.. I'm guessing you're referring to the selected value.. you can use :not as undefined stated

```
$(".selectbox option:not(:selected)").show();
```

You can take out the inline onChange since you are using jQuery.. and bind the change event handler to the select elements on dom ready

```
$(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){   
       var $sel = $('option:selected'); // get all selected options
       $('option').show(); // show all options
       $sel.each(function(i,v){ // loop through selected options
           var $index = $(v).index(); // get index of selected option
           $('select').not($(this).parent()).each(function(){  // loop through other select - not current one       
               if($index != 0){ // not default index
                   $(this).find('option').eq($index).hide(); // hide selected option in other dropdowns
               }
           });
       });    
    }).change(); // <-- trigger change right away
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VE7jA/

Comment: it is still found in the drop down. will also add some info on my question

Comment: the html for your select options would be helpful :)

Comment: yup that's it, something that triggers onload. should i add that in document.ready?

Comment: @magicianIam in my updated answer I put it in document.ready function already `$(function()` == `$(document).ready(function()`

Comment: In your answer can I add specific classes so that i can use two of this function.

Comment: @magicianIam yes.. I made my answer as broad as it could be.. since my examples were using no classes at all.. it would be better to use classes and ids to prevent the code from messing other parts of your page

Comment: i am having some trouble when adding classes to the code. would require some help if it is okay. thank you :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17136/discussion-between-wirey-and-magicianiam)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.selectboxes option:selected').find("option").hide();
```

You are trying to find('option') inside option.. Try this

```
$('.selectboxes option:selected').hide();
```

You can also remove the element once and for all if you are using it again..

```
$('.selectboxes option:selected').remove();
```

To remove a option based on value you can try

```
$('.selectboxes option[value="0"]').remove() ; // Removes option with value 0
```

Comment: can i specify what option to remove, using it's value?

Comment: You can $('.selectboxes option[value="0"]').remove() will remove the option that has value 0

Answer (score 0):

As it's been said, you're trying to find an option within an option, so you'll have to get rid of the `.find` call.

Apart from that, hiding `<option>` elements do not work cross-browser, so you'll have to remove the options instead, and add them back when necessary. There are several ways to manage that, all involving storing the full list of options in a variable (as an array, an object, or even HTML string).

Comment: no worries on that, since this is available for chrome and firefox users only. :)

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to work on Chrome (but Firefox is okay). Try here: http://jsfiddle.net/ksvn9/

Answer (score 0):

Hiding `option` elements is not always supported. A more idiomatic approach would be to disable it.

```
obj.prop("disabled", true);
```

Or simplify it like this.

```
$(".selectbox option:selected").prop("disabled", true);
```

Or this.

```
$(".selectbox").each(function() { 
     this.options[this.selectedIndex].disabled = true; 
});
```